# Getting error while calling URL in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have installed *python3.7* in *ubuntu 14*. Below is the process I followed

1. Downloaded *python 3.7*
2. `./configure`
3. `sudo make`
4. `sudo make install`

Now I am running the follwoing code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
resp = urlopen('http://github.com')
print(resp.read())
```

But it is giving the following errors on console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    resp = urlopen('https://github.com')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 548, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1387, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)`enter code here`
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: try `resp = urlopen('https://github.com')`   - notice `https`

Comment: I tried that snippet of code and it game me no error. Strange.

Comment: The code you wrote looks fine. At least for me there is no error as well. Perhaps, you should check your environment. Is it not better to install from apt? - like: sudo apt-get install python3 ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for error is that your Python is configured and built without SSL support and when `github.com` redirects from `http` to `https` URL, you see this error: `unknown url type: https`.

Check your configure log and you'll see messages about no support for SSL detected.

The solution is install all required dependencies (in this case it is `libssl-dev` or something very similar) and re-configure and re-build Python from source.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `requests.get()` function by importing the `requests` library.
It is working fine on my side on python 2.7

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
print type(r)
print r.status_code 
print r.headers
print r.headers['content-type']
```

**Output :**

```
    <class 'requests.models.Response'>
    200
    {'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Set-Cookie': 'fr=1my64VtKmpcYv2gSs..BcJgcK.TG.AAA.0.0.BcJgcK.AWXA3lHz; expires=Thu, 28-Mar-2019 11:20:42 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; secure; httponly, sb=CgcmXH47CJp-Qfmz1uyl_6eC; expires=Sun, 27-Dec-2020 11:20:42 GMT; Max-Age=63072000; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; secure; httponly', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15552000; preload', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-FB-Debug': 'eP7JRcFDBbaRkLwVBGwHxDrySoaxLgW0z5eCGJibzcznQNszHVs/m0Vhh9v1i6aX5ri+bMmwpbbFnL4fCNNMPQ==', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Date': 'Fri, 28 Dec 2018 11:20:42 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset="utf-8"', 'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'}
    text/html; charset="utf-8"
```